# check radio group value at same index

Tags: jquery

I have two radio groups and when I get first group checked value, I cannot set another group at same index using following code:

```
$('input[name="service_type[]"]:checked').each(function(index) {        
        $("input[name=service_type1["+index+"]]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
```

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=service_type1[0]]

[two input radio button groups named Single and Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyEnm.png)

```
     $service.='<input type="radio" id="str"'.$i++.'"
        name="service_type1[]"
        class="radio-input return" 
        value="'.$request->service_type.'">';


$service.='<input type="radio" id="st"'.$i.'"
        name="service_type[]"
        class="radio-input single" 
        value="'.$request->service_type.'">';
```

Comment: Show html code as well .

Comment: @Swati question updated

Comment: So you need to check same radio in all other divs saloon car ,estate ..etc ?

Comment: I want to check Return button if Single selected of same car

Comment: You can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k9fdLetw/) .

Comment: @Swati plz see updated at code above, I only want jquery to check radio box based upon given index  https://jsfiddle.net/pnxm9zdf/4/

Answer (score 0):

Targeting elements using attr should have `"`, you are missing them.

Instead of

```
$("input[name=service_type1["+index+"]]")
```

Do

```
$('input[name="service_type1[' + index + ']"]');
```

Comment: Do you really have inputs with the name `service_type1[0]`, `service_type1[1]` and so on?

Comment: yes I have it with name `service_type1[]`, and `service_type[]`

Comment: Do you see the difference? your code will target `service_type1[0]`, `service_type1[1]` and so on, depending on how many `input[name="service_type[]"]:checked` elements you have. You posted that you have `service_type1[]` but not `service_type1[0]`. I suggest adding the html code and adding more explanation about the result you are after. Maybe even add images that could explain visually the final result

Comment: I have updated it with image, where two input are there and based upon first one selected, I have to select another at same index

Comment: Could you add another image that will show your wanted result? maybe even a screen cast?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="service_type1[]"]:eq('+index+')').prop('checked', true);
```

solved the issue where `:eq` is index selector used in jquery